# Constant code-completion in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, code-completion

I've just discovered that strg+space brings up suggestions for code completion in NetBeans. This is one of the features I've always loved in Visual Studio and I'm glad that it's available in NetBeans, too. In my opinion IntelliSense does a really good job. On the contrary pressing strg+space to get the suggestions is not very comfortable. I know what to write and only use the auto-completion for variable and method names. Therefore just typing the name is faster than using strg+space and picking a suggestion. I would like the suggestions to be shown always while I'm coding.

Under Tools/Options I've toggled everything on that sounds like "code completion", "auto popup completion window", "auto popup documentation", ... but it's not working. I still have to use strg+space. What shall I do?

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using?  With 6.9.1 I get code completion popping up automatically as soon as I type a `.`.

Comment: I'm using 6.9.1 but I'm not talking of the suggestions that are given after pressing . I want to be given suggestions everytime. When I start a new line and type "JFr" I would like to see "JFrame" in the suggestions. Then I could just press enter and wouldn't have to type "ame"

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ has three auto-complete modes and I find it much more powerful than the same in eclipse/netbeans.

It is annoying to press + if you are not used to it, but sine I have three modes, I want to be able to select which one I want.

Perhaps it is something you will quickly get used to and will do it without thinking about it.

Comment: IntelliJ Community edition is free and open source, so its still value for money.

Comment: Personally I prefer NetBeans. Although IntelliJ certainly is a great editor I don't like the fact that it is after all just a "subset" of the commercial version. However that is just my personal bias. Its features may be equal to NetBeans or Eclipse. I will stay with them and therefore would prefer tips for the editor in question.